# Want to make footer to be sticky on bottom while footer is coming to viewport

Tags: reactjs

Actually I am working in react js.I want to make footer to be sticky at bottom when it enters to view port.

I am using library "react-stickynode".Is there is any option available to make footer sticky at bottom while entering viewport. Tried a lot.But didn't get the solution.